# How do I prevent static methods from calling within different packages?

Tags: java, static

Okay, so my question is probably going to be a bit confusing, so bear with me.

I'm accessing this method from a different class, in a static way
:

```
// Call

GuiHandling.handleGui();

// Method

public static void handleGui()
{
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable()
    {
        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            try
            {
                GUI gui = new GUI();
                gui.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                TabMaker.MAIN_GUI = gui;
            } catch (Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
    do
        General.sleep(10);
    while (!Config.MOVE_ON && !Config.STOP_SCRIPT);
}
```

I have two projects in java, with the exact same package and class naming, I.e. `scripts.gui.guiUtil`

When I run the program, the GUI from the other project loads.

So, essentially what I'm asking, is how would I go about removing the static modifier, and accessing it non-statically so the correct GUI loads?

Note: - I do not have the other class imported
      - It's loading the other GUI as both projects are being run under the same JVM
      - I've tried this: http://java.dzone.com/articles/why-static-bad-and-how-avoid
        but I'm not sure on how to initialize the Client constructor, or even if that will solve my problem.

Thanks in advance, let me know if I can clear anything up, or if I left anything else

Comment: >So, essentially what I'm asking, is how would I go about removing the static modifier, and accessing it non-statically so the correct GUI loads?

You would simply remove the static modifier and then refer to an instance of GuiHandling. What about that are you stuck on?

Comment: Jeff, just corrected me, and claims my problem is that my package names are conflicting. But regardless, when I do such, the problem still occurs. Thanks C:

Answer (score 2):

I don't think the issue here is static vs non-static, it's that you have a conflict in the package names. It sounds like both of them are on your classpath. This is likely to lead to problems because the one that is on your classpath first will be loaded.

You either need to 1) only have one of them on your classpath, 2) change the package naming convention or 3) ensure the one you want to load is before the other one on your classpath. Option #3 is brittle though and easy to break, so only use that as a last resort.